# A Property of Hausdorff Distance

Tags: general-topology, hausdorff-measure

How to prove the Hausdorff Distance between two subsets A and B in a compact metric space X equals 0 if and only if the two subsets A and B have the same closure, i.e. $d_H$$(AB)=0$ if and only if $CL(A)=CL(B)$?

Comment: Were you able to prove any of the implications?

Comment: Suppose the two closures are different.  Say, for example, there is a point $a \in A$, with $a$ not in the closure of $B$.  Can you show $d(A,B) > 0$ then?